# "Ruby on rails" fetching images one by one specifying different sizes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fetching the images from table called galleries.
The field include as id, user_id, pic.
While fetching the images from this table I need to specify each image in different sizes.
All I know is:

> <% @us.each do |p| %>
>         <%= image_tag(p.pics, :size =>"150x300"), :class => "me" %>
>   <% end %>

This will fetch all the images from that table od same size.

How to fetch the images of different sizes?
Example in html code:

```
> <img class="me" src="/images/DSC01145.gif" width="200px"
> height="450px"/>  
> 
> <img class="me" src="/images/DSC01140.gif" width="100px"
> height="200px"/>  
> 
> <img class="me" src="/images/DSC01074.gif" width="100px"
> height="125px"/>  
> 
> <img class="me" src="/images/22.gif" width="175px" height="350px"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: you want to get for each image the size and add it in image_tag parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for the above....

As the images are always 3 in number, So I am writing in view as:

```
 <% a = @us[0] %>   
 <% b = @us[1] %>  
<% c = @us[2] %>   
<%= image_tag(a.gal_pics, :size =>"150x300", :class =>"me") %>  
<%= image_tag(b.gal_pics, :size =>"200x450", :class =>"me") %>  
<%= image_tag(c.gal_pics, :size =>"100x200", :class =>"me") %`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the gem paperclip its great for storing images, and simple to add different size images. Generally people use S3 + Paperclip.

[Paperclip](http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip)